# Suffrage and Vox Populi Badge are almost equal

Tags: support, feature-request, badges

Suffrage: use 30 votes in a day (bronze)

Vox Populi: use 40 votes in a day (bronze)

One of them should be removed because they are almost the same. I see no benefit in having them both.

Answer (score 5):

You are not the first person to point that out (see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/90479/231188) and [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8365/209296)).

If you vote on at least 10 questions, you can vote on 40 posts a day and get *Vox Populi*. If you are only voting on answers, you get *Suffrage* after 30 votes.

It appears that for some people, voting on questions is extremely hard (see this: [Why aren't people voting for questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9508/231188)). That is why there *Vox Populi* badge was added to encourage them to vote on questions, rather than changing rules for the older *Suffrage* badge.

Comment: Okay, I vote mostly on questions though